# How to create a function that renames all levels of a factor with the last 3 characters of the level

Tags: r, r-factor

I am new to programming in R and I have to create a function `end.levels` that receives an `f` factor and, using a function that I designed earlier (I will attach it below), I have to rename all its levels to have only the 3 last letters of the original level.
The function must return the factor with the renamed levels, ** without modifying the factor data ** but only the levels (and this will automatically affect the data).

That is, I have to create a function (using if it can be the 'final' function) that returns me the last 3 characters of all the elements of a factor.

The function that I had designed and on which we should base ourselves is this:

```
finales <- function(v, n){
  substr = substr(v, nchar(v) - (n - 1), nchar(v))
  return(substr)
}
```

I have tried to do this but I think I am getting very complicated:

```
finales.niveles <- function(f){
  substr.var = substr(f, nchar(labels(fac) - 3), nchar(labels(fac))
  new.niv = rename(substr.var)
  return(new.niv) 
}
```

I had read that the nchar () function does not accept factors, for this you have to do nchar (labels (f)), where f is the factor but I am not sure if this is like that or like that.

When I test my function it returns this error:

```
 Error in labels (fac) - 3: non-numeric argument for binary operator
```

This is the test factor that the function must pass:

```
fac = factor(c("Alto","Bajo", "Mediano", "Bajo", "Alto", "Alto", "Mediano"))
```

The goal is to return us: "lto", "ajo", "ano", "ajo", "lto", "lto", "ano"

Here are some tests that the function must pass:

```
all(renom == c("lto", "ajo", "ano", "ajo", "lto", "lto", "ano"))
```

If anyone can help me with this I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: `substr` won't work on a `factor`. It will work on the levels of a factor. So you can't use `finales(fac, 3)` (throws an error), but you can use `finales(levels(fac), 3)`.

Comment: The last hint I'll give is that you can modify the level of a factor directly. That is you can use `levels(fac) <- ...` where the `...` is the levels you want it to have.

Comment: The goal is to return: "lto", "ajo", "ano", "ajo", "lto", "lto", "ano"

Comment: I understand your goal. This seems like homework, so I am trying to help you with hints and not solve it for you completely.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
> fac <- factor(c("Alto","Bajo", "Mediano", "Bajo", "Alto", "Alto", "Mediano"))
> gsub('.+(...)$', '\\1', as.character(fac))
[1] "lto" "ajo" "ano" "ajo" "lto" "lto" "ano"
```

Comment: can u explain me that? i understood the regular expression, but the replacement \\1? what is that? thank you